# List of Fifth Generation Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I'm looking for a list of all the new Pokemon in Black and White. Specifically, I'd like a list with their English names and pictures. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Asking about unreleased games, aren't we? ;)

Comment: @badp: Haha, I suppose I am though only by a couple of days. Have mercy oh great badp =P

Comment: It's okay, I trust the lists behind the links will be seamlessly updated in place as more official information is released.

Comment: This has a lot of lack of research. I don't get how it good positive votes!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Bosspvz2 - Probably becuase its from 2011 when the types of questions we allowed was still pretty loose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PokemonDb has a nice list](http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/game/black-white) showing sprites (pictures) and has the confirmed English names.

Answer (score 3):

I found this after using badp's link:

[List of All Pokemon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number#Generation_V)

It links to the same place that badp's answer does, but it has the number/picture/name/type all in one area for quick perusal.

Answer (score 2):

Legendary Pokémon has a list of all the new Pokémon's English name next to their number, picture, and Japanese name [here](http://www.legendarypokemon.net/bw/names).

Comment: This list doesn't seem to be complete, or in order.

Comment: @Raven >.< oops, that's the old list from when they were first announced. Edited. ;)

Comment: After the edit: Oh cool, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of [5th generation pokémons](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_index_number_(Generation_V)) on Bulbapedia; if you want only the new entries I suggest you instead take a look at [this list](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_native_to_the_Unova_region) of Pokémon specific to the new region, [Unova](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova).

Comment: Wow. Bulbapedia has improved a lot compared to Serebii since last I checked.

Comment: -1, doesn't have English names.

Comment: @Disgruntled If that's true, it's a problem with the Bulbapedia, as the link at the bottom named "English" gives the same names shown in that table.

Comment: the names shown in the table are the romanisations of the Japanese names, not the actual English names. They do list a few English names confirmed by Nintendo but not the full list which, while technically not officially confirmed, has been proven true beyond any doubt.

Comment: Well looks like Bulbapedia finally stopped being anal and added the real names: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Dex

Answer (score -2):

I can't do the pictures, but here is a list of the names: (From starter town to end game)

- Oshawott (water starter)
- Dewott
- Samurott
- Snivy (Grass starter)
- Servine
- Serperior
- Tepig (Fire starter)
- Pignite
- Emboar
- Patrat
- Watchog
- Lillipup
- Herdier
- Stoutland
- Purrloin
- Liepard
- Pansear(fire)
- Simisear
- Panpour (water)
- Simipour
- Pansage (grass)
- Simisage
- Munna
- Musharna
- Pidove
- Tranquill
- Unfezant
- Blitze
- Zebstrika
- Roggenrola
- Boldore
- Gigalith
- Woobat
- Swoobat
- Drilbur
- Excadrill
- Audino
- Timburr
- Gurdurr
- Conkeldurr
- Tympole
- Palpitoad
- Seismitoad
- Throh
- Sawk
- Sewaddle
- Swadloon
- Leavanny
- Venipede
- Whirlipede
- Scolipede
- Cottonee
- Whimsicott
- Petilil
- Lilligent
- Basculin (red-striped and blue-striped)
- Sandile
- Krokorok
- Krookodile
- Darumaka
- Darmanitan
- Maractus
- Dwebble
- Crustle
- Scraggy
- Scrafty
- Sigilyph
- Yamask
- Confagrigus.

### Fossils

- Tirtouga
- Carracosta
- Archen
- Archeops.

### Regular PKMN again:

- Trubbish
- Garbador
- Zorua
- Zoroark
- Minccino
- Cinccino
- Gothita
- Gothorita
- Gothitelle
- Solosis
- Duosion
- Reuniculus
- Ducklett Swanna
- Vanillite
- Vanillish
- Vaniluxe
- Deerling
- Sawsbuck
- Emolga
- Karrablast
- Accelgor
- Escavalier
- Foongus
- Amoongus
- Frillish
- Jellicent
- Alomomola
- Joltik
- Galvantula
- Ferroseed
- Ferrothorn
- Klink
- Klang
- Klinklang
- Tynamo
- Eelektrik
- Eelektross
- Elgyem
- Beheeyem
- Litwick
- Lampent
- Chandalure
- Axew
- Fraxure
- Haxorus
- Cubchoo
- Beartic
- Cryogonal
- Shelmet
- Stunfisk
- Meinfoo
- Mienshao
- Druddigon
- Golett
- Golurk
- Pawniard
- Bisharp
- Bouffalant
- Rufflet
- Briaviary
- Vullaby
- Mandibuzz
- Heatmor
- Durant
- Deino
- Zweilious
- Hydreigon
- Larvesta
- and Volcarona.

### Legendaries

- Cobalion
- Terrakion
- Virizion
- Tornadus
- Thunderus
- Landerus
- Reshiram
- Zekrom
- Kyurem
- Keldeo
- Meloetta (Two forms
- like Keldeo
- Tornadus
- Thunderus
- and Landerus) and Genesect.

Comment: Ironically for the amount of downvotes this got it's probably the best answer here. At least it wont suffer from link rot

Comment: UPVOTE THIS!!!!!!!!!