# How many Pokemon are there as of X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Before *Pokemon X* and *Pokemon Y* there were 649 Pokemon in the National Pokedex, not including variant forms.

How many new Pokedex entries does *Pokemon X/Y* add and what are the total number of Pokemon now?

Particularly:

- Do the new Mega Pokemon each have their own entry in Pokemon X/Y's National Pokedex?
- Does Pokemon X/Y have a National Pokedex? What's the highest National Pokedex number of a Pokemon in X/Y?
- Does Pokemon X/Y have any legendary Pokemon like Mew, which aren't normally encountered and haven't been officially announced yet but might still appear at the end of the Pokedex? (This may be harder to answer than previous generations, since 3DS ROMs are harder to hack and therefore mine for raw Pokedex information.)

Comment: Although this question was previously closed as Pokemon X/Y had not been released at the time. I'm re-opening it as it's already the global release date in Australia and Japan.

Comment: When you say "Previously closed" are you referring to another question, as this one has only existed for 7 minutes?

Comment: I don't like this question because it demonstrates very little effort, or more likely, none at all.  Yeah, it's *technically* a valid question, but I don't think it was asked in good faith.

Comment: While I went ahead and answered it because I was just looking at this like 20 minutes ago, I agree that this question shows serious lack of research.

Comment: I believe it's a valid question. For example, moderator badp approved of a question asking for [a list of all fifth-generation Pokemon](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17452/3454), even though the question could be answered by "check Bulbapedia". This question is especially important since many sources online are incomplete and pieced together from trailers, and there is currently dispute over whether Mega Pokemon each have their own Pokedex entry.

Comment: @JonathanDrain No one's arguing it's not a valid question (otherwise, I'm sure we'd have seen close votes by now). I do, however, agree with fbueckert about it being lazy and game-y.

Comment: Ask Psychic Robert ;D

Comment: This question needs more votes. It is waaaay better than the "list of generation 5 pokemon", no offense,

Comment: Why is this question marked down!? I see no problem with it even if it was asked a little early it is a good question.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't that many entirely new Pokemon in this generation...some people are upset about this.  Not counting mega evolutions (which I don't believe appear in the Pokedex as normal), [the count is believed to be up to 718 as of this writing](http://www.screwattack.com/news/entire-kalos-pokedex-leaked-spoilers).

Answer (score 2):

*A more updated answer:*

There are 720 confirmed Pokemon (not including forms) that appear in the Kalos national dex. However hackers have found 1 more, Volcanion, although it has officially been revealed yet. That makes the total Kalos count (as far as we know) to be **721**.

This means in total the number of new Pokemon in Kalos is **71**.

Mega evolutions do not take up another space, as they are really just a form change, and not an evolution.

*Source: [http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pokémon_by_National_Pokédex_number](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number)*

Comment: Update: Volcanion has since been revealed officially. http://www.pokemonrubysapphire.com/en-gb/pokemon/volcanion

Answer (score 0):

As of now the total count is 718 of this writing.  I am currently aware of at least 68 pokemon for XY.  I am assuming there will be at least 100 new pokemon so it should be above 750 in total.

Mega do not have their own pokedex entry, which makes it little harder to know which ones do.  However I guess that we will just have to create or search for a list of mega pokemon.

There are three pokedex in Kalos.  Central, Coastal, and Mountain.

Comment: ... and National.